# Replacing Nth character in String array in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell and functional programming in general. I am trying to implement a function to take a list like this

```
["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

and want to be able to replace the xth character in the yth element for example

```
replaceChar 1 2 'd' arr
```

would produce

```
["abc", "ded", "ghi"]
```

So essentially the first parameter is the element and the second is the position of the string, the third is the character and last is the [String].

The signature of this function looks like this:

```
replaceChar :: Int -> Int -> Char -> [String] -> [String]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yourself? Show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 5):

First a note: while your signature is perfectly fine, you really don't use the fact that you're dealing with character strings, it could just as well be lists of any other type. It's usually a good idea<sup>1</sup> to manifest that in your signature by using a completely generic *type variable* (lowercase letter) instead of `Char`:

```
replaceAtXY :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

Next, note that basically the problem can be reduced to modifying the *n*-th element of an ordinary (non-nested) lists. On the outer list, you modify the *y*-th sublist, namely, in that sublist you modify the *x*-th element.

So what does "modifying" mean in Haskell? We can't *mutate* elements of course<sup>2</sup>. We need a function that takes a list and returns another one, and does this based on a function which operates on single elements of the list.

```
modifyNth :: Int -> (a->a) -> [a]->[a]
```

Observe that this is somewhat similar to the standard function `map :: (a->b) -> [a]->[b]`.

Once you have that function, you can easily implement

```
modifyXY :: Int -> Int -> (a->a) -> [[a]]->[[a]]
modifyXY x y f nList = modifyNth y (modifyNth x f) nList
```

(BTW the `nList` parameter doesn't need to be written, you can [*η*-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_reduction#.CE.B7-conversion) it).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>As to *why* this is a good idea: obviously, it allows you to *use* the function in more general settings. But more importantly, it gives the type checker extra information that you won't do anything with the contained elements themselves. This actually helps to catch a lot of bugs in more complicated applications!</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Actually you can, even with rather nice semantics, in the ST monad.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Let's break this problem into two functions, one that replaces an element in a string with a new char, and one that does this for a list of strings.

I would recommend something like:

```
replaceCharInStr :: Int -> Char -> String -> String
replaceCharInStr 0 c (s:ss) = c:ss
replaceCharInStr n c (s:ss) = s : ???
replaceCharInStr n c [] = error "replaceCharInStr: Empty string"
```

here we say that if `n` is 0, ignore the first element of the string with `c`, then if `n` is not 0 and the list has at least one element, prepend that element in front of something (exercise left to reader. Hint: recursion), then if our string is empty, raise an error.  I will say that I don't particularly like that `error` is used here, it would be much better to return a `Maybe String`, or we could say that `replaceCharInStr n c [] = [c]`.  We could also change the type signature to `replaceCharInStr :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]`, since this isn't specific to strings.

For the next function, what we'd like to do is take an index, and apply a function at that index.  In general, this function would have type

```
applyAt :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
```

And could be implemented similarly to `replaceCharInStr` with

```
applyAt :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
applyAt 0 f (x:xs) = f x : xs
applyAt n c (x:xs) = x : ???
applyAt n c [] = error "applyAt: Empty list"
```

In fact, this is the exact same shape as `replaceCharInStr`, so if you get this one implemented, then you should be able to implement `replaceCharInStr` in terms of `applyAt` as

```
replaceCharInStr n c xs = applyAt n (\x -> c) xs
-- Or                   = applyAt n (const c) xs
```

Then your `replaceChar` function could be implemented as

```
replaceChar :: Int -> Int -> Char -> [String] -> [String]
replaceChar n m c strings = applyAt n (replaceCharInStr m c) strings
-- Or                     = applyAt n (applyAt m (const c)) strings
```

All that's left is to implement `applyAt`.

Comment: StackOverflow needs some indicator about work in progress by other answerers... simultaneous near-identical answers are somehow depressing. (Yours is a bit more complete of course.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree, but at least this way OP ends up with two similar answers worded differently, which can often be useful for understanding the problem better.  Even if the explanation is the same, sometimes I find it better two have two different people explain it as the precise wording used can help make things "click".  You have a great answer, too, and you mention a few things I didn't, such as immutable variables and eta-reduction, which are good to know about.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Edward Kmett's Lens package, then your example is a one-liner:

```
import Control.Lens
["abc", "def", "ghi"] & ix 1 . ix 2 .~ 'd'
```

returns

```
["abc","ded","ghi"]
```

Lens can emulate the indexing and property access you'd expect from an imperative language, but in Haskell. If you're just beginning to learn Haskell, you should probably wait a bit before using Lens. It's clever and powerful but it's also large and complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
replace n 0 c (x:xs) = (replace' n c x) : xs
replace n m c (x:xs) = x : (replace n (m-1) c xs)
  where
    replace' 0 c (x:xs) = c : xs
    replace' n c (x:xs) = x : (replace' (n-1) c xs)
```

Here you just traverse the list until the corresponding index is `0` and we replace the character in the matches list. We use the same principle for replacing the charachter in the list. We traverse it and when we reach the specified index, we replace the character at that index by our new one.

In the end, everything gets consed bak on each other to replace the old structure, this time with the character replaced.

Comment: This gives me an error that Not in scope: replace' at the second line

Comment: @BobTheBuilder Corrected it

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what the function does, but for some reason replace' is not in scope. I do have the correct indentation, not sure why it is giving the error. So I tried to split the function into two different functions and I'm getting the error that text is not in scope.

Comment: Simplified and removed the out of scope error (hopefully) (mobile answering, sorry :D)

Comment: No worries! But for some reason it is still out of scope, if I rewrite it as two separate functions replace and replace' it doesn't seem to work. It runs but the array didn't replace the value.